# sql query to select a value from one database 

Tags: sql

Hai,

I have two database and I want to select one value from one of the databases....
for that I want to pass one value and if that value is stored in the database I want to pick the id representing the value in the database.

that means the operation is that.....

first I select a row of data from one database by using a user control...
in that row there is a value (example "apple") and I want pass this value("apple") to the second database...  in the second database the value("apple") having a id (example "australian") I want that the query search for that  id("australian") and show that in the text box.

Please  help me....
thanks to all advance....

example

```
first database

id     name      details
1      apple     sweet
2     orange     sweet
```

second database

```
id                  name          details
Australian        apple         sold
Indian            banana        sold
```

Imagine that there are the two databases....
using a user control I select first row from first database and I want to pass that value apple to second database and find out the id australian from the second database and show that in a text box....

thank you.........

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join between the two databases as long as you use the fully qualified prefix for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for the join , your query should look something like this

```
SELECT SecondDataBase.TableName.Id  
FROM   FirstDatabase.TableName INNER JOIN
       SecondDataBase.TableName ON FirstDatabase.TableName.["Column contains Apple"] = SecondDataBase.TableName.["Column contains Apple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualified table name, which includes server name, db name, schema and table (e.g. MySqlServerInstance1.mydb1.dbo.table1) name will definitely work as long as one database server has a registered reference within a calling DB server. See this for things you have to do if you are using MS SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you normally reference a table using SchemaName.TableName

```
dbo.Fruit
```

The database is automatically determined by your connection string. FirstDatabase

So when you use dbo.fruit, the server automatically appends the database name to the table like

```
FirstDatabase.dbo.Fruit
```

If the user account has permission, you can select from a completely different database by specifying the database

```
SecondDatabase.dbo.FruitSales
```

To take it even further you can select from an entirely different SQL server if you have set up a linked server by specifying the linked server name like

```
SecondServer.ThirdDatabase.dbo.FruitShipping
```

So you can join between a table in your database and a table in your second database like

```
SELECT * 
FROM FirstDatabase.dbo.Fruit AS F INNER JOIN 
     SecondDatabase.dbo.FruitSales AS FS ON F.Something = FS.Something
```

But you can even join between a table in your database and a table on a different server like

```
SELECT * 
FROM FirstDatabase.dbo.Fruit AS F INNER JOIN 
     SecondServer.ThirdDatabase.dbo.FruitShipping AS FS ON F.Something = FS.Something
```